# mysql - Do DDL statements replicate under Row Based Replication if the Default Database is not set?

Tags: mysql, replication, ddl

In `Statement Based Replication` the `Default` Database is of paramount importance.

e.g.

```
replicate-do-db=dbTwo

USE dbOne;
UPDATE dbTwo.tableTwo . . . .
```

will fail as `dbOne` has been set as the default database.

Whereas under Row Based Replication it should be fine as it looks at the database that is changed rather than the default.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#option_mysqld_binlog-do-db

However, with `Row Based Replication` all DDL statements are replicated as Statements.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log-setting.html

> With the binary log format set to ROW, many changes are written to the
>   binary log using the row-based format. Some changes, however, still
>   use the statement-based format. Examples include all DDL (data
>   definition language) statements such as CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, or
>   DROP TABLE.

So in that case does the default database come into play.

e.g.

```
replicate-do-db=dbTwo

USE dbOne;
ALTER TABLE dbTwo.tableTwo . . . .
```

will that fail to execute as `dbOne` is the default, or will it succeed as it is `dbTwo` that has been changed?

All the examples I can find refer to `UPDATE` statements, and are quite clear on what will and wont work.

But I can't find any examples that refer to DDL statements using `Row Based Replication`.

(n.b. I'm currently using MySQL 5.5 in case that makes a difference - upgrading is not an option any time soon)